# VMware Workstation's "Edit/Paste" uses the wrong keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware workstation on Windows 8.1 to run a Debian machine. Since I have an French keyboard, I've changed the layout in the guest to `azerty`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration && sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

When I paste some text in the guest using VMware's menu Edit/Paste, it appears as if it was typed on a qwerty keyboard.

So for instance if I copy in windows the phrase "**The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!**", VMware will paste in Debian "**The auick brozn fox ju;ps over the lqwy dog/**".

Comment: Try installing VMware Tools in the guest so that you can get real clipboard sharing.  Without Tools, Edit > Paste mimics a normal paste by replicating keystrokes.

Comment: I have had some issues with vmware tools, maybe that's it

Comment: I have tried removing it and re-installing it a bunch of times, but the issue is still there. I can't change the resolution either, so I guess my VMware tools install is completely broken.

Comment: I guess I'll have to create a new debian install ; I can't get VMware tools to work anymore. @jamesdlin, write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, you can change your keymap to us with the following command.

```
setxkbmap us
```